# Parcel build issues when importing all modules on remote hosts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, babeljs, parceljs

Experimenting with Three.js within a React application, I've prototyped an example that works locally; however, fails to load remotely from static hosts such as GitHub or Amazon S3.

If I run [my GitHub project](https://github.com/jasonsturges/threejs-react-example) locally, it works:

```
$ parcel index.html --open
```

However once I build a distributable and push to [my GitHub Pages](https://jasonsturges.github.io/threejs-react-example/), the script fails to execute - just a blank page.  All CSS and JavaScript are being loaded, but no errors are present in the console.

```
$ parcel build index.html --public-url '.'
```

Strangely, I can use `serve` on the exact same build and it works locally.

My initial thought was just paths, to which I added `--public-url '.'` to my Parcel build command.  All scripts seem correctly pathed, and loaded.

It seems like the issue may stem from importing all modules as:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

It may be coincidence, but I have [another GitHub project](https://github.com/jasonsturges/pixi-react-example) that exhibits the same problem on [GitHub Pages](https://jasonsturges.github.io/pixi-react-example/) when importing all modules.  To sanity check, I do have React projects using Parcel that build and deploy without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Percel did not support periods in the name.

As in: `username.github.com` wouldn't work.

This has sense been fixed, per [GitHub issue #2093](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2093).